# CakePHP and Composer installs -- how to use it for Plugin and Vendor dependencies for a CakePHP 2.x application

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php

I am having some weird issues with `git submodule update` for a Plugin dependency with Jenkins @ CloudBees.

So I am switching some, if not, all my dependencies from `git submodule` to `Composer`.

I came across this repo called `composer installers`. https://github.com/composer/installers

I was wondering how to use this for both Plugin and Vendor dependencies.

I am not familiar with Composer and even after reading the docs, I am uncertain how to say, place this dependency specifically to Plugin/xxx

I know how to do this with `git submodule add`.

So anyone knows how I should use Composer or better yet, Composer installers, please advise me.

To make things easier, I want to use 2 actual examples.

- https://github.com/milesj/Utility is to be placed inside my app/Plugin/Utility
- https://github.com/simkimsia/php-gd-simpleimage is to be placed inside my app/Vendor/SimpleImage

Comment: You'll have to write your own `composer.json` inside your project and detail all the plugins. Essentially you have to add composer support to all your non-composer plugins manually inside your project. It's doable but it's very tough to achieve. I gave up in the end.

Comment: This may help: http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/07/23/migrating-svn-apps-to-git-and-composer/

Answer (score 1):

There is a Composer plugin for CakePHP that has a [Backery article](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/uzyn/2012/06/20/composer_plugin_for_cakephp) about it. The code is available on Github:
https://github.com/uzyn/cakephp-composer

It's actively being developed (last commit was yesterday), but in my early use of it (today), it seems to be working as expected.

[Packagist](http://packagist.org) has loads of Compose-ready libraries. Some of them are CakePHP related. Some are not.

The two examples you listed aren't in Packagist (yet?). Thankfully, Composer makes it possible to work directly with Git (and other VCS) repos. For the milesj/Utility plugin (which has a `composer.json` file), you'll need to follow the [Repositories](http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository) guide in the Composer docs to set things up properly.

For the php-gd-simpleimage repo, you'll need to write a `composer.json` file, then follow the Repositories steps.

One of the most confusing things about Composer is that `composer.json` is the same system/file-format for both libraries and "projects." Really, they're all the same to Composer. In your "project" repo, though, you're only outlining requirements (usually), not making your application installable via Composer. Regardless of their locations, both `composer.json` files are for the same thing: tracking and installing dependencies. You can imagine it as a tree with your project (and it's `composer.json`) at the top, and then a branching dependency tree all the way down.

Happy Composing!